# Any apps for "progressive" language learning like Toucan?

Tags: learning-methods, resource-request

What I mean by "progressive" language learning:

1. The student starts by learning a small amount of vocabulary and grammar.
2. When practicing the foreign language, the student replaces the native words that he/she knows, e.g.

I learn German -> Ich learn Deutsch.

3. The student then learns more vocabulary and grammar.
4. After the student has learned enough words, he/she can start speaking less native words.
5. Steps 3 and 4 are repeated until the student can speak the foreign language fluently.

This is similar to how *Toucan* works, but as one uses it for longer, the number of native words will not decrease.